# Rotate view using CGAfffineTransformRotate

Tags: objective-c, uiview, rotation, cgaffinetransform

I have a circular image which I am trying to rotate, so that the yellow and black striped circle stays under the user's finger and rotates in both directions. I have this so far:

```
- (void)handleJogShuttle:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    UIView *shuttle = [recognizer view];

    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
        [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        [recognizer view].transform = CGAffineTransformRotate([[recognizer view] transform],M_PI / 20.0f);
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[shuttle superview]];
    }
}
```

[image]

Also, currently, the slightest movement can cause the view to rotate in a full circle, which is obviously not desired.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this method gets called A LOT. Try using `NSLog` and check how many time it does.
Anyway, you are not calculating the angle properly,  you could try using

```
-(CGPoint)translationInView:(UIView *)view
```

from the recognizer to calculate the correct angle to rotate.

Comment: How would i use translationInView, as it returns a CGPoint, not an angle? thanks

Comment: Find out the center of your circle and calculate the angle from the previous point to the current using the inverse sine our inverse cosine. Its not too complicated, but you would have to compensate for the radial translation. It's hard for me to explain it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "RotationTestViewController.h"

@interface RotationTestViewController()
-(void)transformSpinnerwithTouches:(UITouch *)touchLocation;
-(CGPoint)vectorFromPoint:(CGPoint)firstPoint toPoint:(CGPoint)secondPoint;
-(void)animateView:(UIView *)theView toPosition:(CGAffineTransform) newTransform;
@end
@implementation RotationTestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches)
    {
        // Send to the dispatch method, which will make sure the appropriate subview is acted upon
        //    currentTouch=touch;
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches){
        // Sends to the dispatch method, which will make sure the appropriate subview is acted upon
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch=[[event allTouches]anyObject];
    if (touch.view==Spinner)
    {
        [self transformSpinnerwithTouches:touch];
    }
}

-(void)transformSpinnerwithTouches:(UITouch *)touchLocation
{
    CGPoint touchLocationpoint = [touchLocation locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint PrevioustouchLocationpoint = [touchLocation previousLocationInView:self.view];
    //origin is the respective piont from that i gonna measure the angle of the current position with respective to previous position ....
    CGPoint origin;
    origin.x=Spinner.center.x;
    origin.y=Spinner.center.y;
    CGPoint previousDifference = [self vectorFromPoint:origin toPoint:PrevioustouchLocationpoint];
    CGAffineTransform newTransform =CGAffineTransformScale(Spinner.transform, 1, 1);
    CGFloat previousRotation = atan2(previousDifference.y, previousDifference.x);
    CGPoint currentDifference = [self vectorFromPoint:origin toPoint:touchLocationpoint];
    CGFloat currentRotation = atan2(currentDifference.y, currentDifference.x);
    CGFloat newAngle = currentRotation- previousRotation;
    temp1=temp1+newAngle;
    NSLog(@"Angle:%F\n",(temp1*180)/M_PI);
    newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(newTransform, newAngle);
    [self animateView:Spinner toPosition:newTransform];
}

-(void)animateView:(UIView *)theView toPosition:(CGAffineTransform) newTransform
{
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0750];
    Spinner.transform = newTransform;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

//-(CGFloat)distanceFromPoint:(CGPoint)fromPoint toPoint:(CGPoint)toPoint
//
//{
//float x = toPoint.x - fromPoint.x;
//float y = toPoint.y - fromPoint.y;
//return hypot(x, y);
//}

-(CGPoint)vectorFromPoint:(CGPoint)firstPoint toPoint:(CGPoint)secondPoint
{
    CGFloat x = secondPoint.x - firstPoint.x;
    CGFloat y = secondPoint.y - firstPoint.y;
    CGPoint result = CGPointMake(x, y);
    //NSLog(@"%f %f",x,y);
    return result;
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    [Spinner release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```