# Rotating an image problem

Tags: iphone, rotation, touch

I'm trying to rotate an image by just touch and move.

Here is my code for rotating the view

```
[myView.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0)];
```

**CODE INSIDE touchMoved**

```
CGPoint Location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

Float32 Angle = (atan2(Location.x - myView.layer.center.x, Location.y - myView.layer.center.y));

myView.layer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-Angle);
```

Now everything works fine except one

If I rotate from the middle of the view then all work fine but when I try to rotate it from corners the it jumps and make my touch point as center (remember i have made lower right side corner of the view fixed, see the anchor point). I just have to rotate the view up to 90 degree but only using single finger touch... I'm not sure if I was able to describe my problem correctly but problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put the code from the  following link as it :[Rotate the image on the same center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370227/rotate-view-using-cgafffinetransformrotate/4645194#4645194)