# How to make arrow in specific direction using cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, direction

I want two few objects in one row, like below and have an object shooting them from downwards, like as below

```
                0 0 0 0 0 0 




                     0
```

The lower be always on its position, and will shoot to uper one, 
I want to make arrow as user will move its finger on the screen of iPhone, like below

```
                 0 0 0 0 0 0 

                   \
                    \
                     \
                      0
```

if move finger then

```
                  0 0 0 0 0 0                             
                      |
                      |
                      | 
                      0
```

In move one finger on screen more towards right, then arrow should move respectively as

```
                  0 0 0 0 0 0                             
                          /
                         /
                        /
                      0
```

How can I implement this logic, should I have multiple images of arrays and use them according to angle, or what, but I want accuracy in it.

Thanks

Comment: @nikhildhamsaniya, should I use these touch methods and gesture in cocos2d project, you mean that?

Comment: obviously you can  there you can use touch move method as well as touch gesture method also   find the link for gesture http://www.raywenderlich.com/2343/how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites-with-cocos2d

Comment: and for touch move find all the method tutorial from http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:lesson_2._your_first_game

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need of multiple images.... just rotate your arrow image in touchesMoved method

Try that code.

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];


// Set up initial location of projectile
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

// Rotate player to face shooting direction
CGPoint shootVector = ccpSub(location, sprite.position);
CGFloat shootAngle = ccpToAngle(shootVector);
CGFloat cocosAngle = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(-1 * shootAngle);

CGFloat curAngle = _player.rotation;
CGFloat rotateDiff = cocosAngle - curAngle;    
if (rotateDiff > 180)
    rotateDiff -= 360;
if (rotateDiff < -180)
    rotateDiff += 360;    

CGFloat rotateSpeed = 360; // degrees per second
CGFloat rotateDuration = fabs(rotateDiff / rotateSpeed);

[yoursprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                    [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:rotateDuration angle:cocosAngle],
                    [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(finishShoot)],
                    nil]];
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit code, of touchMove body, rather than only idea,

Comment: Anush I will try this, and as it worked, I will upvote you :-)

Comment: Thanks for your precious time :-)

Answer (score 1):

check the following link to rotate image on  touch move

here you have to restrict angle between your desire angles

[rotate image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370227/rotate-view-using-cgafffinetransformrotate/4645194#4645194)

Comment: I saw that, but can you see that only arrow direction be moved, not the image wherever let me give u demo example for this http://www.bubbleshooter.net/

Comment: See this link, and see the movement or arrow,

Comment: you need to mix up arrow moving logic  in tick method for arrow animation

Comment: Thanks for your time, should I implement than upvote or now :-P

Comment: it's up  to you when you get your desire result and if the you feel the answer is use full for others too

Answer (score 0):

As Anshul and Nikhil stated, rotating the arrow should adequately answer your problem.

Note additionally that you will probably need to create your arrow sprite with an anchor set at its bottom center ( 0.5, 0.5 ), to avoid noticing your arrow shift left and right, depending on your setup.

Best,